# PHPMailer echo's from successful sent email

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hello I finally got PHPMailer to work with Google but now I am finding out that I am getting this output to the screen after the message has been sent.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP f34sm21891943qco.35
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [76.28.109.170] 250-SIZE 35651584 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 OK f34sm21891943qco.35
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 OK f34sm21891943qco.35
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Go ahead f34sm21891943qco.35
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 OK 1276700936 f34sm21891943qco.35
```

I was wondering if there was any way to remove this output so the users don't see it?

Answer (score 9):

Set the `$phpmailer->SMTPDebug` property to 0, you probably left it on debug (at least, I detect some work has been done from the '*finally*'). http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=properties

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php

 require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Enable SMTP debugging. 3 disable=0
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                               

//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();            

//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";//or your domain

//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          

//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = "your email";                 
$mail->Password = "your email password";                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
//Set TCP port to connect to 
$mail->Port = 587;                                   

$mail->From = "your email";
$mail->FromName = "your name";

$mail->addAddress($userMail, $uname);

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
//$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

// you can also comment the echos here out
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}

?>
```

`enter code here`Check this image at line 8.
You can also comment out the if(!$mail->send()){ } else{} block
[image]